# Hibernate - Get all table names in a Database

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, rcp

I am trying to get all the table names in a database(Oracle 11g) to dynamically generate checkboxes for each table in the UI. I have not mapped any of these tables in the .cfg.xml file.

I used the below code :

```
List<Object> list = sessionProd.createQuery("select table_name from user_tables").list();                               

for(Object l : list){
    System.out.println("L : " +l.toString());
}
```

But it errored as below :
  ***org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: user_tables is not mapped [select table_name from user_tables]***

Please let me know if there is any way to get all table names in Hibernate 4

Comment: Try List<String>, and for(String s: list ) should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a native SQL query method resolved the problem. Thanks for your suggestions.

The following code worked for me:

```
List<Object> list = sessionProd.createSQLQuery("select table_name from user_tables").list();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use SQL query, not HQL query

```
sessionProd.createSQLQuery("select table_name from user_tables").list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the query is not proper. Try with the below snippet

```
List<Object> list = sessionProd.createQuery("show tables from Database_name").list();
```

Comment: `createQuery()` is used for HQL queries only

Answer (score 0):

change the query string with select table_name from all_tables

```
List<Object> list = sessionProd.createQuery("select table_name from all_tables").list();                               

for(Object l : list){
     System.out.println("L : " +l.toString());
}
```

Comment: It shows all the tables in the database (not just the ones present in the schema I have mapped). Also the method should be <b>createSQLQuery</b>

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate would return Exception to you in such case because you have not mapped user_tables. If you want to get all table names you should to create SQLQuery, that would return to you that you need. You can use HQL (createQuery) only for mapped tables